# How to pass parameter to a function using dojo connect?

Tags: javascript, dom-events, dojo

I would like to use `dojo.connect` to connect a function  that called on the `onclick` of  a `button`. But in that button click there is an argument passed to that function. How to pass an argument to that function using `dojo.connect`?

Answer (score 1):

I see that this question was asked over 6 months ago, so I'm answering to simply close the loop to a problem that I too struggled w for way too many hours.  Since I'm not at the level of other folks on this forum, there's probably better ways of solving this issue, but here's a way that works in my app.  Please feel free to improve on my answer.

The short answer is to call dojo.hitch in the 3rd argument of the connect syntax, and then pass your arguments in the 3rd argument of the hitch syntax.

I read tons of articles on 'connect', including virtually everything I could find on dojotoolkit.org, and for some reason a 2010 post on David Walsh's blog http://davidwalsh.name/dojo-connect pulled it all together for me.

```
*objname*.connect(*objname*.domNode, "onclick", dojo.hitch(null, *stringFunctionName*, *passedArgument*)
```

That said, here's what my working statement looked like for my dynamically created dojox.mobile.ListItem...

```
liEntry.connect(liEntry.domNode, "onclick", dojo.hitch(null, "loadEntryDetails", jsonEntry[i]));
```